# How to use collect method with three params i.e "collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)" to add integers in a list

Tags: java, java-stream

Being a beginner to java functional programming, I need some help on `collect()` that takes into consideration the three params i.e `list.parallelStream().collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)`. How can i calculate sum of salary all employees mentioned in the list.

```
public class SumMethodsOfCollectorclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.add(new Employee(6, "Nick", 27, "Software Engineer", 44000f));
      list.add(new Employee(9, "Tom", 23, "Civil Engineer", 32000f));
      list.add(new Employee(3, "Jon", 29, "Mechanical Engineer", 37000f));
      list.add(new Employee(4, "Harry", 21, "Surgeon", 55000f));
      list.add(new Employee(8, "Don", 25, "Laywer", 50000f));
      list.add(new Employee(7, "Marry", 20, "Police", 29000f));
      list.add(new Employee(2, "Angel", 22, "Professor", 35000f));
      list.add(new Employee(1, "Kate", 23, "Teacher", 29000f));
      list.add(new Employee(5, "Evan", 22, "Pilot", 44000f));

      sumOfAgeOfAllEmployees(list);
      sumOfSalaryOfAllEmployees(list);
    }

    private static void sumOfAgeOfAllEmployees(List<Employee> list) {
      Integer result = list.stream().parallel().collect(Collectors.summingInt(i -> i.getAge()));
      System.out.println("The sum of age of all employees - " + result);
    }

    private static void sumOfSalaryOfAllEmployees(List<Employee> list) {
      // to get the sum of salary of all the employees
      list.parallelStream().collect(supplier, accumulator, combiner)
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly about it is unclear to you? Have you read the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer))? It also has an example.

Comment: Note that `collect` is not the best tool for the job of summing integers, as it is about having mutable containers that the elements are added to. Instead, have a look at `reduce`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform this mutable reduction using an atomic integer. This may mean additional cost in a sequential stream, but here's how it would work:

```
private static int sumOfSalaryOfAllEmployees(List<Employee> list) {
    AtomicInteger res = list.stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary)
            .collect(AtomicInteger::new, 
                     AtomicInteger::addAndGet, 
                     (ai1, ai2) -> ai1.addAndGet(ai2.get()));

    return res.get();
}
```

You may also want a custom class to use for the accumulation of values (if synchronization in AtomicInteger is unnecessary overhead):

```
private static class IntHolder {
    private int value;

    public IntHolder() {
    }

    public IntHolder(int val) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void add(int val) {
        this.value += val;
    }

    public void accumulate(IntHolder other) {
        this.value += other.value;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
private static int sumOfSalaryOfAllEmployees(List<Employee> list) {
    IntHolder res = list.stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary)
        .collect(IntHolder::new, IntHolder::add, IntHolder::accumulate);

    return res.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your supplier needs to return a mutable result container.

An AtomicInteger will do, or an custom IntHolder class. Or a MutableInt from apache commons-lang3:

```
    MutableInt sum = list.parallelStream().collect(
            () -> new MutableInt(0),
            (sum1, employee) -> sum1.add(employee.getSalary()),
            (sum1, sum2) -> sum1.add(sum2.intValue())
    );
```